# Integrating Vector/Raster in Google Cloud Storage in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, export, google-cloud, repository

I was looking at the new feature of QGIS 3.2 which can integrate between Google Cloud Storage and QGIS. I'd like to save all >20 GB GIS Dataset into Cloud rather than in my local disk. Can I do that?

What should I fill on *'Bucket/container'* and *'Object Key'* sections?

[image]

Comment: The bucket is the ID of the bucket in the google cloud storage system. Have you created a project and a bucket in the google cloud? https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-console

Comment: Suppose I had a bucket called zzz_huts (yes, it exists)

Is the bucket:
zzz_huts       or   gs://zzz_huts        or
the URL I get by right clicking and "copy link"?
https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/zzz_huts;tab=objects?forceOnBucketsSortingFiltering=false&project=civil-tempo-236700              or      something else?

Answer (score 1):

The Google Cloud Storage stores an object of any file type, You store objects in containers called buckets that you've created, example:

- Bucket name - gs://mybucket
- Object name - gs://mybucker/image.png

Each object has its own individual url, the Object Key.

I would recommend reading the extensive google docs for further information on Google Cloud Storage and other GCP feature. [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/introduction)